# Bower components without component.json

Tags: github, bower

Looking at the [available components on Bower](http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/), the very first repository ([accounting.js](https://github.com/josscrowcroft/accounting.js)) doesn't seem to have a `component.json`-file. Reading through the documentation, this seems to be required in order to be added as a Bower-component.

How is this possible?

---

**Edit:**
Besides adding a component.json-file, it will also work when you follow the [semver-specification](http://semver.org/). This seems not to be the case because there are two JS-files in the root (accounting.js and accounting.min.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Bower doesn't yet have any [validation](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/53) when registering a component, which means anyone can register anything. This is the reason some components in the registry are invalid. Validation is mainly waiting for the server part to be [ported to Node.js](https://github.com/twitter/bower-server/issues/1).

A `component.json` is always recommended, but only required if you have multiple files and/or dependencies, otherwise Bower will infer the version from the git tags.